# getIntent().getExtras() is retuning Null when we open banner notification android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

XMPP Server is sending notification to topic with data payload, when android app is in background. Client android app which uses FCM notification is also receiving the same and showing the banner notification.

But when we try to parse the data in main activity oncreate method, It shows Null.But our app needs to get the request id and open the corresponding page in this case.

```
    // getExtras not containing the notification data: 
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }
    }
```

XMPP Server is sending the below data when android app is on background

```
<message><gcm xmlns='google:mobile:data'>{"to":"/topics/xxxx","content_available":true,"collapse_key":"sample","delay_while_idle":true,"delivery_receipt_requested":true,"priority":"high","data":{"message":"{\n  \"id\" : \"xxx\",\n  \"reqId\" : \"1234\"},"time_to_live":10000,"notification":{"sound":"default"},"message_id":"685989336783482201"}</gcm></message>
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Seems like you have things set up correctly, could you add your gradle dependencies to the question?

Comment: Updated my question with gradle dependencies..

Comment: Facing the same issue. Have you resolved it?